# printf returning line length at end of line

Tags: c++, printf

Every time I print out a printf statement, the length of the line is tacked on to the end. For example:

```
cout << printf("%s", "foo") << endl;
cout << printf("%s", "foobar") << endl;
```

shows in my console:

```
foo3
foobar6
```

An interesting bug, anyone know what it is? I'm using MinGW g++ as my compiler.

Comment: It's doing exactly what you told it to do.  Print `foo` then print the length of that output, then a newline-and-flush, then print `foobar` then print the length of that output, then a newline-and-flush.

Comment: Your code is equivalent to `printf("%d\n", printf("%s", "foo"));`

Comment: Why do you think it is a bug?

Comment: *"An interesting bug"* - it's not a bug, at least not in the code. It's doing *exactly* as you asked it to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement

```
cout << printf("%s", "foo") << endl;
```

is equivalent to

```
int res = printf("%s", "foo");
cout << res << endl;
```

The [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) function prints the string, and returns the number of characters it printed. Then `cout << ...` prints that integer value and the newline.